# VBA Sum between Special Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Hope you are all doing well. Im here because of a question Im trying to solve since this morning and I CANT stand it anymore.
That is the context : I have an excel workbook in which I have different sheets containing different business plans for different countries. My goal is to make a consolidated Income statement with the sum of the criteria (COGS, Net profit, Salaries....) in each sell.

Each cell in the A column corresponds to a criterion and I want the numbers to appear in the B column (Total of all companies for each criterion).

Thats my code : Initially it wasnt like this but thats one of my attempting drafts let me explain below why Im trying this format

```
Private Sub Consolidated_Income_Statement()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Consolidated As Worksheet

For Each Sheet In Sheets
    Do While Cells(B2, B152) <> ""
    Consolidated = Sum(Call BPs, B152)
    GoTo Consolidated
Next
End Sub

Sub BPs()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Right(Sheet.Name, 50) = "E2016" Then
End Sub
```

The fact is that I want to sum the cells only of the sheets containing "E2016" and Im trying to create a call button to use it my private sub once I have determined that I only want these E2016 sheets.

And thats how I tried to do it initially

```
Private Sub Consolidated_Income_Statement()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Consolidated As Worksheet
For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Right(Sheet.Name, 50) = "E2016" Then
        Do While Cells(B2, B152) <> ""
        Consolidated = Sum('I WANT TO SELECT MY E2016, B152)
        GoTo Consolidated
        Next
End Sub
```

But nothing is working ! Sorry if these questions are too basic but Im learning VBA on my own for my company since 2 days and Im facing a couple of difficulties ! Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like below?

```
Private Sub Consolidated_Income_Statement()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Consolidated As Integer
For Each Sheet In Sheets
    If Right(Sheet.Name, 5) = "E2016" Then
        Consolidated = Consolidated + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet.Range("B2:B152"))
    End If
Next

MsgBox "Sum is : " & Consolidated

End Sub
```

Comment: If this has answered your question please mark it as answered (greyed out tick to the left of answer)

Comment: I responded higher, couldnt press shift or enter here hehe

Comment: the sum line is referencing the sheets sum function and putting the range of B2:B152 through the sum this is then added to consolidated. the message box is purely to show the sum after it can be removed when you implement the solution

Comment: Yes I will thick it ! Just : Ok the code is working (No compile errors) but how do I tell Vba that I want to insert this results in my sheet called Consolidated in Cells ranging from B2 to B152. Because nothing is happening right now! Thanks for your time

Comment: Im a bit confused. Consolidated is the sheet you want the sum to appear? The sum is only 1 value and you want that value copied over B2:B152? What range do you want sumed up on the "E2016" sheets? Or have I completly missed this?

Comment: Sorry ! Didnt see you answered !! Thanks for your help thats the code that I finally found in order for you to understand :